# Execution halts at CFQuery

Tags: sql, coldfusion, sql-insert, cfquery

For some strange reason this simple INSERT statement in my CFQUERY tag just halts the page load.  I have plenty of SELECT statements around my site, but the results on screen output the "Before SQL" dump and then end.

It must be something simple that I am missing. I have even used the hard-coded values below to test the statement before adding the dynamic CFPQUERYPARAM from the submitted FORM values.  The datasource is declare for application in application.cfc

Thank you for the assist.

```
<cfdump var="Before SQL" abort="false" />

<cfquery name="insertResponses" result="insertResults">

    INSERT INTO StudentResponseTable
    VALUES
        (102, 1, 39, 1)

</cfquery>

<cfdump var="After SQL" abort="false" />

<cfdump var="insertResults" abort="true" />
```

Comment: wrap it in a try/catch block. The issue is probably you're not listing out your column names

Comment: Anything in the application log on the server? I would stick it in a Try / Catch and log the error. Are there definitely only 4 columns in that table?

Comment: I've had the column names also, but I'll see what else I can glean from a try/catch

Comment: Turn on de-bugging and see if the query shows up.  Also, if have an onError function in your Application.cfc, comment it out so you can see the error message on your screen.

Comment: Not related to your question, but your final cfdump needs octothorps around the variable name.

Comment: I am newer to Coldfusion, and professional software, so I need to become more through with my programming (eg. try/catch, onError).  The dumped results from the catch block showed the exact values I was submitting were being rejected as duplicate PK

Comment: So I turst you can take it from here.

Comment: Yep.  I will try and use more try/catch blocks going forward.  Thank you everyone.

Comment: BTW, do not know if you saw DanBracuk's comment but - if this is a DEV environment, definitely turn on debugging and/or temporarily comment out any error handlers so you can actually *see* the errors as you work on the code :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the suggestions above I added a try/catch and learned from the 'catch' I was running into a duplicated PK on the SQL table.